# solrJ error in HttpSolrServer and SolrServer

Tags: solr, solrj

I have add the .jar files in java library , and try to connect to the solr, the code is below:

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.QueryResponse;
import org.apache.solr.common.params.ModifiableSolrParams;

public class SolrQuery {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, SolrServerException {
    SolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8080/solr");
        ModifiableSolrParams params = new ModifiableSolrParams();
        params.set("q", "1");

            QueryResponse response = server.query(params);

            System.out.println("response = " + response);

  }
}
```

But when i try to run the program , i got error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    SolrServer cannot be resolved to a type
    HttpSolrServer cannot be resolved to a type
    The type org.apache.solr.common.params.SolrParams cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

How can i solve it?

Comment: add collection name the url or set collection name.

Comment: @vinod i am new in the solr , can be more specific?

Comment: check the answer.

Comment: This sounds like an Eclipse problem - are you using Eclipse? How are you compiling? How are you attempting to run the program? How have you added the jars to the project? Which jars have you added?

Comment: Is it because of the .jar files? i have imported: commons-io-2.5,httpclient-4.4.1,httpcore-4.4.1,httpmime-4.4.1,jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7,noggit-0.6,slf4j-api-1.7.7,stax2-api-3.1.4,woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1,zookeeper-3.4.6,solr-solrj-6.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the server URL add collection/core name, where you indexed documents.

SolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8080/solr/collection");

Example Java Code For Your reference.

`*` gives all documents indexed into solr. change `*` to keyword string you want to search.

```
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrQuery;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.QueryResponse;
import org.apache.solr.common.SolrDocumentList;

public class SearchSolr {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SolrServerException {
        HttpSolrServer solr = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1");
        SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
        query.setQuery("*"); 
        QueryResponse response = solr.query(query);
        SolrDocumentList results = response.getResults();
        for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); ++i) {
          System.out.println(results.get(i));
        }   
    }   
}
```

Comment: sry , i just tried your code ,and got same error:                                 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 The constructor HttpSolrServer(String) is undefined
 The method setQuery(String) is undefined for the type SolrQuery
 The method query(SolrQuery) is undefined for the type HttpSolrServer
 The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Comment: did you add solrJ jar files ?

Comment: These are the files i have imported:  commons-io-2.5,httpclient-4.4.1,httpcore-4.4.1,httpmime-4.4.‌​1,jcl-over-slf4j-1.7‌​.7,noggit-0.6,slf4j-‌​api-1.7.7,stax2-api-‌​3.1.4,woodstox-core-‌​asl-4.4.1 
  ,zookeeper-‌​3.4.6   ,solr-solrj-6.5‌​.0

Comment: is it showing errors before compling. ? I guess you have not downloaded jars and added to you java project classpath properly. recheck on that.

Comment: yeah , import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer; and import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrQuery; in red line ,  but i have import all the jar files in the solr lib ,  i am very confused

Comment: Are you using eclipse IDE. ?

Comment: If yes, do these steps. 1:right click on your project, build path -> configure build path->libraries->add external jars->browse and select jars files

Comment: sry , the problem still not fixed,could you please go to following link to answer , i have write the problem more detailed,   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43425136/trouble-in-solr-connect-java