# trouble in solr connect java

Tags: solr, solrj

I try to use solr 6.5.0 to connect java . I have added following .jar files to the library:

```
commons-io-2.5
httpclient-4.4.1
httpcore-4.4.1
httpmine-4.4.1
jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7
noggit-0.6
slf4j-api-1.7.7
stax2-api-3.1.4
woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1
zookeeper-3.4.6
solr-solrj-6.5.0
```

but when i try use following code to connect the solr:

```
import org.apache.http.impl.bootstrap.HttpServer;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrQuery;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.QueryResponse;
import org.apache.solr.common.SolrDocumentList;

public class SolrQuery {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws SolrServerException {
    HttpSolrServer solr = new HttpServer("http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1");
    SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
    query.setQuery("*"); 
    QueryResponse response = solr.query(query);
    SolrDocumentList results = response.getResults();
    for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); ++i) {
      System.out.println(results.get(i));
    }   
  }   
}
```

before i compile it, I got an error in the:

```
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrQuery;
HttpSolrServer solr = new HttpServer("http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1");
```

Can anyone help me how to solve it?

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: i can not compile code,  when i run the code , it says:    HttpSolrServer cannot be resolved to a type
 The constructor HttpServer(String) is undefined
 The method setQuery(String) is undefined for the type SolrQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The piece of code in your question was written for an old version of Solr before ver. 5.0. You'll find many sources and example around written for old Solr versions, but in most of the cases all you have to do is change the old `SolrServer` class with the new `SolrClient` (and now correct) class.

Both were the representations of the Solr instances you want to use.

Read the [Solr Documentation - Using SolrJ](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Using+SolrJ)

I warmly suggest to not use for your classes the same name of an already existing class (in your example your class is named `SolrQuery`).

The catch all string for Solr queries is `*:*` which means: search any match for all available fields. So change the statement `query.setQuery` into:

```
query.setQuery("*:*");
```

I suppose you're using a Solr client for a standalone instance so, as you're already aware, the correct way to instance a `SolrClient` is:

```
String urlString = "http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted";
SolrClient solr = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(urlString).build();
```

And this is an easier way I suggest to iterate through all returned document:

```
for (SolrDocument doc : response.getResults()) {
   System.out.println(doc);
}
```

Have a look at the documentation of [`SolrDocument`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_5_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/common/class-use/SolrDocument.html) class that explain how to use it and correctly read field values.

Answer (score 2):

I founded that i need to import a .jar file which is not contain in the /dist library which named  `slf4j-simple-1.7.25`  , and also

```
HttpSolrServer solr = new HttpServer("http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted");
        SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
```

need to change to the

```
 String urlString = "http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted";
    SolrClient solr = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(urlString).build();
```

after that it finally can run already!!!